# How do I change the React Admin delete pop up dialog text (material-ui)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, material-ui, react-admin

At the moment I have the following code:

```
<List {...props} bulkActionButtons={false}>
        <Datagrid>
            <DeleteButton undoable={false} />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

The pop asks me if I really want to delete this item with the following UUID...

In matters of UX I have to display the title of the item to delete, NOT the UUID.

Neither do I want to use that undo stuff, so I have set it to false.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you try using a custom translation? They are not just for multilingual applications but rather allow to replace any text, including placeholders.